# How to get marker options on marker click?

Tags: angular, ionic3, google-maps-markers, ionic4

I am working in ionic 4 and using the google maps api. I have a couple of markers which I build up like this:

```
setRestaurantMarkers() {
    const markers = [];
    this.singletonService.restaurants.results.map(restaurant => {
        const restaurantPosition = {lat: restaurant['Restaurant'].Lat, lng: restaurant['Restaurant'].Long};

        this.markerOptions = new Marker({
            position: restaurantPosition,
            title: restaurant['Restaurant'].Name,
            category: restaurant['RestaurantCategory'].Name,
            map: this.map
        });

        this.marker = new google.maps.Marker(this.markerOptions);
        this.marker.addListener('click', (marker) => {
            // Set destination for navigate button
            this.destination = [marker.latLng.lat(), marker.latLng.lng()];
            console.log(marker.latLng.lat(), marker.markerOptions);
            this.markerClicked = true;
        });
    });
}
```

But I am not able to get `markerOptions` details when I am clicking the marker. I would like to have this `markerOptions` when clicking on the marker is that possible I can't find anything about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assign marker Options in a var instead of class property

```
setRestaurantMarkers() {
    const markers = [];
    this.singletonService.restaurants.results.map(restaurant => {
        const restaurantPosition = {lat: restaurant['Restaurant'].Lat, lng: restaurant['Restaurant'].Long};

        const markerOptions = new Marker({ // make it as const
            position: restaurantPosition,
            title: restaurant['Restaurant'].Name,
            category: restaurant['RestaurantCategory'].Name,
            map: this.map
        });

        this.marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
        this.marker.addListener('click', (marker) => {
            // Set destination for navigate button
            this.destination = [marker.latLng.lat(), marker.latLng.lng()];
            console.log(marker.latLng.lat(), markerOptions); // get directly
            this.markerClicked = true;
        });
    });
}
```